# [Shopware6]: Extend the configuration of another Plugin

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have successfully extended multiple Plugins by using decorators and symfonys dependency injection.

But right now, i need to extend or overwrite the config.xml of another Plugin. How could i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Updated answer

I think I read your question wrong. In case you want to alter not the output of config values but the config itself, you may decorate the `ConfigReader` service.

```xml
<service id="MyPlugin\Decorator\ConfigReaderDecorator" decorates="Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\Util\ConfigReader">
    <argument type="service" id="MyPlugin\Decorator\ConfigReaderDecorator.inner"/>
</service>
```

```php
class ConfigReaderDecorator extends ConfigReader
{
    private ConfigReader $decorated;

    public function __construct(ConfigReader $configReader)
    {
        $this->decorated = $configReader;
    }

    public function getConfigFromBundle(Bundle $bundle, ?string $bundleConfigName = null): array
    {
        $config = $this->decorated->getConfigFromBundle($bundle, $bundleConfigName);

        if ($bundle->getName() === 'NameOfThePlugin') {
            // overwrite or extend the config of another plugin
            // var_dump($config);

            // add a new card with a new field to the existing config
            $config[] = [
                'title' => [
                    'en-GB' => 'A new card injected',
                ],
                'elements' => [
                    [
                        'component' => 'sw-text-field',
                        'label' => 'A new field injected',
                        'name' => 'nameOfInjectedField',
                    ],
                ],
            ];
        }

        return $config;
    }
}
```

#### Old answer

Decorate the `SystemConfigLoader` service.

```xml
<service id="MyPlugin\Decorator\SystemConfigLoaderDecorator" decorates="Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigLoader">
    <argument type="service" id="MyPlugin\Decorator\SystemConfigLoaderDecorator.inner"/>
</service>
```

```php
class SystemConfigLoaderDecorator extends AbstractSystemConfigLoader
{
    private AbstractSystemConfigLoader $decorated;

    public function __construct(AbstractSystemConfigLoader $decorated)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function getDecorated(): AbstractSystemConfigLoader
    {
        return $this->decorated;
    }

    public function load(?string $salesChannelId): array
    {
        $config = $this->getDecorated()->load($salesChannelId);

        // overwrite the config values
        $config['NameOfThePlugin']['config']['pluginConfigFieldName'] = 'foobar';

        return $config;
    }
}
```